# Trouble finding the volume of a solid $y^2=2x, x=2y$

Tags: calculus, integration

I think I'm finally beginning to get the hang of these problems but I'm having trouble with this one:

Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line (about the $y-axis$):

$$y^2=2x, x=2y$$

The first thing I did was draw the graph.  After drawing the graph I figured out that a slice would be that of a washer.  So I figured I need to make $y$ a function of $x$.

$$y^2=2x$$
$$\frac{y^2}{2}=x$$

And next I figured I needed to find points of intersection so I did the following:

$$y^2=2(2y)$$
$$y^2=4y$$
$$y=0, y=4$$

I took those to be the bounds of my function.  So now I sought to find the area of the washer using the following formula:

$$A=\pi R^2-\pi r^2$$
$$A=\pi(R^2-r^2)$$

So plugging in my functions:

$$A=\pi((2y)^2-(\frac{y^2}{2})^2)$$

Simplifying this I get:

$$A=\pi (4y^2-\frac{y^4}{4})$$

But when I integrate using the following:

$$\pi \int_{0}^{4}4y^2-\frac{y^4}{4}dy$$

My anti-derivative is:

$$\pi [\frac{4y^3}{3}-\frac{y^5}{20}]|_{0}^{4}$$

But my answer is incorrect.  Do you all know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What was the line (axis of rotation) specified in your problem?

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz Sorry I forgot to include that.  It's about the $y-axis$

Comment: Looks perfect to me.

Comment: @TedShifrin I also thought it was correct but it definitely is not.  The only clue I have as to the correct answer is a $15$ in the denominator.

Comment: I get $\frac{512\pi}{5}$

Comment: Make sure you copied the problem correctly. Be warned: Often answers at the back of the book are wrong! $x$ a function of $y$, btw. Sounds like you screwed up arithmetic, not calculus. You get a denom of $15$ with what you have here!!

Comment: My answer is $\frac{512\pi}{15}$. Everything you wrote before giving the final answer was correct. You did not show detail there, I assume it was a slip of arithmetic near the end. Substituting, I get $\pi\left(\frac{4^{4}}{3}-\frac{4^5}{20}   \right)$. The second term is $\frac{4^4}{5}$, now bring to a common denominator of $15$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you, I was doing something weird with finding the common denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CW answer to push it off unanswered queue:

Answer is $\frac{512\pi}{15}$. Everything you wrote before giving the final answer was correct. You did not show detail there, I assume it was a slip of arithmetic near the end. Substituting, I get $\pi(\frac{4^4}{3}−\frac{4^5}{20})$. The second term is $\frac{4^4}{5}$, now bring to a common denominator of $15$.

(André Nicolas)